# Blender won't show my obj files

Tags: import

[image]I go to open and go to where I put my obj files and they don't show in blender.
It does not show my files anymore.

Comment: Obj. files should be imported. So not *Open* rather than *Import* menu item in the Info header if I understand correctly what are you doing. Screenshots could help to visualize the problem

Comment: I tried to use import but it didn't open my file

Comment: "not Open rather than Import menu item in the Info header". You are opening .blend file via File > Open in the Info header, it won't ever open obj. file. You need to use File > Import > Wavefront (obj).